# Using multiple entities in a model (Zend Framework 2)

Tags: php, model, zend-framework2

Is the use of multiple Entities in one Model allowed in the Zend Framework 2?

I have multiple tables and there are relations between it. Now I want to make it with a folder structure like this.

**Book Model**

- Zend/module/BookStore/src/BookStore/Model/Book/**Book**.php
- Zend/module/BookStore/src/BookStore/Model/Book/**BookReview**.php
- Zend/module/BookStore/src/BookStore/Model/Book/DataMapperInterface.php
- Zend/module/BookStore/src/BookStore/Model/Book/IdentityMap.php
- Zend/module/BookStore/src/BookStore/Model/Book/Factory.php
- Zend/module/BookStore/src/BookStore/Model/Book/IdentityMapFactory.php
- Zend/module/BookStore/src/BookStore/Model/Book/MySQLDataMapper.php

Book and BookReview are entities. Am I allowed to use it like this or do I need to make a model for each table I have?

Comment: What do you mean with "entities"? If you want to use your classes as database entities in connection with Zend/Db classes like TableGateway or RowGateway you should use separate classes for model, like you did in your example.